# What are continuous integration build health metrics?

Tags: svn, jenkins, continuous-integration

I would like to create reports for dev teams with overview of their continuous integration builds health status. We use SVN as repository and Jenkins to execute CI builds so a lot of information is available.

Do you know any useful metrics besides Successful Build Rate & Build Repair Rate that could be added to such report and could be easily implemented in Jenkins?

Comment: On topic under "practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession" per FAQ

Answer (score 1):

Statistics of your CI servers might be execution time (ideally 1 integration per checkin), time it takes until builds are fixed and how often the build is red vs total number of builds.

Other interesting metrics to evaluate resp. update would be (good) *code metrics* (aka software metrics) such as % of code duplicated, bugs per project respective file (in order to spot modules that might need refactoring), complexity measure such as Cyclic Complexity, lint checks, coding standards, test coverage.

Various links I just googled:

- http://www.thinkinginagile.com/2011/07/continuous-integration-build-metrics_16.html
- http://www.thepragmaticarchitect.com/2006/12/15/code_metrics.html
- http://www.ndepend.com/metrics.aspx

**Addendum**
Perhaps you like the [CI game](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/The+Continuous+Integration+Game+plugin) which keeps a score on how developer affect the integration status.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was thinking about metrics that can be calculated using Jenkins. Successful Build Rate & Build Repair Rate are good examples. I'm wondering if there are any other similar to them.

Comment: While I like the concept of the CI Game, when I installed it on our Jenkins machine, other developers didn't like it because it "ranked them."  (Yes, this is cultural issue, but worth noting.)  The results can also be skewed because all contributors to build receive the same score for the build regardless of what caused the score.  (e.g. 4 developers contribute, 1 developer caused the build to fail, all 4 loose points)

Comment: Yeah having n developers contributing to a failed integration means n-1 innocent bystanders. Therefore being fast enough to have mostly 1 change per integration aids developers acceptance a lot.

Comment: Notice that NDepend can produces reports from CI build http://www.ndepend.com/sample-reports/ and also integrates both in Visual Studio and VS Team Services https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ndepend.ndependextension